# Local AjaxStart/Stop?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a global ajax start and stop. I am wondering though if this can be overridden by a local one as one of my ajax methods needs to do something different when ajax starts and stops

I tried like

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  },
  ajaxStart: function()
{
  alert('hi');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to another function (successHandler) or even to a function by name since all global functions actually become a method of the window object. For that last solution, all you need to do is a add a string variable to you public and local pages that contains the right function name.

```
function successhandler()
{
    $(this).addClass("done");
}

function ajaxStart()
{ alert('hi');
}

$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: successHandler,
  ajaxStart: window['ajaxStart']
});
```

Comment: Wont the the other jquery ajaxStart still run?

Comment: No. When you call this ajax method, you specify a single callback for each of the events. Which callback that is is up to you.

Comment: I am also using ajaxmanager plugin so not sure if it can work with this(through my test it does not work) http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/

Comment: I don't know this Ajax manager, but anywhere where you declare an inline function, you should be able to use an explicitly declared/named function too, as long as you omit the parentheses in the assignment.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by setting `global:false` in your jQuery.ajax call.

> global (Boolean)
>   Default: true
>
> Whether to trigger global Ajax event
>   handlers for this request. The default is true. Set to false to
>   prevent the global handlers like ajaxStart or ajaxStop from being
>   triggered. This can be used to control various Ajax Events.